# htaccess: replace hypen with plus sign and Redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a question on Redirect url + replacing hypen with plus sign before redirect

http://www.example.com/new-items/school-first-item/school-second-item

I want to redirect above url to http://www.example.com/web/school+second+item

Here is the rule, where I am able to redirect, but not sure how to replace the hypen with a plus before 301 redirect

```
RewriteRule ^/?new-items/?([^/]+)/([^/]+) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/web/$2 [R=301,NC,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this *before* the rule you already have:

```
RewriteRule ^new-items/?([^/]+)/(.*)-(.*)$ /new-items/$1/$2+$3 [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

Good practice is to avoid multiple redirects to browser and try to process all rewrites internally in same request and then make one final redirect for converted URL.

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess for this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# replace new-items/[^/]+ by web and all the - by + **repeatedly**
RewriteRule ^(?:web|new-items/[^/]+)/([^-]*)-(.*)$ web/$1+$2 [DPI,E=redir:1]

# if env var is set and no more - left then do a final redirect to browser
RewriteCond %{ENV:redir} =1
RewriteRule ^web/[^-]+$ $0 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Test this after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.